# How can I convert a number to a base58 string?

Tags: web3.js, getprogramaccounts, base58, memcmp

I need to convert a number (ex. 1, 2, 32, 43, etc) into a base58 string in order to use it in getProgramAccounts memcmp filters. I'm able to do this with strings, but I've been unable to find a function that works properly with numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation for bs58:

> encode(input) input must be a Uint8Array, Buffer, or an Array. It
> returns a string

`const bs58_string = bs58.encode(Uint8Array.from([2]))`

Comment: Thanks!  This worked out. It turns out I also had a small mistake on my offset that was messing things up

Answer (score 0):

install npm package "bs58" (npm install bs58), Documentation link https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58

try snippet

```
const bs58 = require('bs58');
const number = '503503503958';
const bytes = bs58.decode(number);
console.log(Buffer.from(bytes).toString('hex'));
```

if you just need to convert the value to bs58 (or verify) than you can use this website https://www.browserling.com/tools/base58-encode

Comment: I get a `Invalid param: DecodeError(InvalidCharacter { character: '0', index: 0 })` when I try this?  This is a u32 number in the struct.  What string should I expect for example, for the number 2

Answer (score 0):

This will actually depend on the *representation* of the number, not only its value

| Value |  | `u8` | `u16le` | `u32le` | `u64le` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 1 | 11 | 1111 | 11111111 |
| 1 |  | 2 | 5R | 2UzHM | Ahg1opVcGX |
| 2 |  | 3 | 9q | 3xyZh | LQM2cdzDY3 |